# iOS and Objective-C Training in Melbourne

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm sure this is not the correct forum for this but figured it was pretty close.

Does anyone know of any courses in Melbourne Australia for iOS development?

I've been developing in the MS arena my whole life and am looking at getting into Objective-C with regards to mobile devices but cannot seem to find any courses.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out an [iOS/iPhone Developer Training (Melbourne/Sydney)](http://jtribe.com.au/2011/02/iphone-developer-training/) by [jTribe](http://jtribe.com.au/)

[image]

Schedule:

> **DAY ONE:** Introduction to iPhone Development and the Objective-C
>   Language On day one we start with Objective-C and will cover
>   everything needed to start building iPhone applications. We will  dive
>   straight into the core Objective-C syntax and constructs, use of Xcode
>   as a development tool, the Foundation  framework, how to build your
>   own Objective-C classes, properties and methods, a thorough
>   explanation of memory  management issues on the iPhone and will use
>   Xcode and GDB to debug an iPhone app. 
>   **DAY TWO:** Building a basic iPhone
>   application, using Interface Builder, Views, View Controllers & Table
>   Views Day two starts with the build of a complete iPhone app. We then
>   look in depth into views, the iPhone view hierarchy,  the concept of
>   delegates, Interface Builder and view controllers. We look in more
>   detail into table views, navigation  and navigation controllers and
>   learn techniques to ensure that our app can scale in the real world.
>   
> **DAY THREE:** Application Navigation, Animation and Multi Touch,
>   Deployment, Provisioning Profiles and the App  Store. On day three we
>   look at image handling, resources and how to create those beautiful
>   custom table cells. We  then go on to interacting with web services
>   and building our very own Twitter client before we take a deeper look
>   at  the development and deployment process, iTunes connect, the App
>   Store and marketing